# Update row with select on same table

Tags: sql, sql-update

I'm trying to update row with same table query. Context:

```
ID        |  LANG       |  TEXT
----------------------------------
1         |  EN         |  Hello
1         |  FR         |
1         |  ES         |
2         |  EN         |  Boat
2         |  FR         |  Bateau
2         |  ES         |
```

I want to :
For each row; if *TEXT IS NULL*; update it with TEXT value of row with same ID and LANG = 'EN'.

What is the SQL request to do something like that ?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You don't specify the database.  The following is standard SQL:

```
UPDATE t
    SET TEXT = (SELECT text
                FROM t t2
                WHERE t.id = t2.id AND LANG ='EN' AND
                      TEXT IS NOT NULL
               ) 
    WHERE TEXT IS NULL;
```

In the event of duplicates, the following should work:

```
UPDATE t
    SET TEXT = (SELECT max(text)
                FROM t t2
                WHERE t.id = t2.id AND LANG ='EN' AND
                      TEXT IS NOT NULL
               ) 
    WHERE TEXT IS NULL;
```

EDIT:

Of course, not all databases support all ANSI standard functionality.  In MySQL, you would use a `join` instead:

```
UPDATE t JOIN
       (SELECT id, max(text) as text_en
        FROM t t2
        WHERE LANG ='EN' AND TEXT IS NOT NULL
       ) ten 
       ON t.id = ten.id
    SET t.TEXT = ten.text_en
    WHERE t.TEXT IS NULL;
```

Comment: Hi, with MySQL i've got this error when trying your query: #1093 - You can't specify target table 't' for update in FROM clause

Comment: Thank's for MySQL specific query !

Comment: I used that last code snippet to convert a varchar to a datetime with `STR_TO_DATE('20180308163241639', '%Y%m%d%H%i%s%f')`

Answer (score 10):

For MS SQL you can use a join to do this, it might not work with other databases though:

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.text = t2.text
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table1 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id 
WHERE t1.TEXT IS NULL AND t2.LANG = 'EN'
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/26202/4)

Comment: Worked very well for what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE TABLE
SET TEXT = (SELECT TOP 1 text WHERE id = table.id AND LANG ='EN' AND TEXT IS NOT NULL) --TOP 1 INCASE YOU HAVE DUPLICATES
WHERE TEXT IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Update Test T1  INNER JOIN (SELECT T2.ID AS "id",MAX(T2.TEXTV) AS "MTEXT" FROM TEST T2
                             WHERE T2.LANG = 'EN'
                             AND T2.TEXTV IS NOT NULL   
                             GROUP BY T2.ID ) AS DER          
            ON T1.ID = DER.id

SET T1.TEXTV = DER.MTEXT
WHERE T1.TEXTV IS NULL ;   ------MySQL Query
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE TABLE
    SET
        TEXT = (SELECT TOP 1 text WHERE id = table.id AND LANG ='EN' AND TEXT IS NOT NULL) 
WHERE
    TEXT IS NULL;
```