# Update each row of the table with data from table itself

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a problem with updating work table - values from that table come from table itself. Here is my table:

```
+----------+----------+-----+---------+
| EVEN_KEY | INVE_KEY | QUA | QUA_MAX |
+----------+----------+-----+---------+
|        1 |        2 |   1 | NULL    |
|        2 |        2 |   2 | NULL    |
|        3 |        2 |   3 | NULL    |
|        1 |        1 |   2 | NULL    |
|        4 |        2 |   3 | NULL    |
+----------+----------+-----+---------+
```

What I would like to do is update column qua_max - summarize column qua for given inve_key for each row. So, results in above table should look like after update:

```
+----------+----------+-----+---------+
| EVEN_KEY | INVE_KEY | QUA | QUA_MAX |
+----------+----------+-----+---------+
|        1 |        2 |   1 | 9       |
|        2 |        2 |   2 | 9       |
|        3 |        2 |   3 | 9       |
|        1 |        1 |   2 | 1       |
|        4 |        2 |   3 | 9       |
+----------+----------+-----+---------+
```

And here is my problem - query from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25266878/update-row-with-select-on-same-table) example is giving me error, I can not even run it. What is wrong?

Error:

[image]

Query:

```
UPDATE @TEMP_FINAL
    SET QUA_MAX = (SELECT SUM(QUA)
                FROM @TEMP_FINAL t2
                WHERE @TEMP_FINAL.INVE_KEY = t2.INVE_KEY 
                GROUP BY INVE_KEY
               )
```

EXAMPLE TABLE:

```
DECLARE @TEMP_FINAL TABLE
(
    EVEN_KEY INT,
    INVE_KEY INT,
    QUA INT,
    QUA_MAX INT
)

insert into @TEMP_FINAL (even_key, inve_key, qua)
values(1, 2, 1), 
(2,2,2),
(3,2,3),
(1,1,2),
(4,2,3)
```

Comment: It's really silly, but when used as an object name in a multi-part name, escaping a table variable name is necessary. `WHERE [@TEMP_FINAL].INVE_KEY = ...` will make the query work syntactically (the result will not match your desired result, but I think that's an error on your part). There are other ways of doing this, as some of the answers point out.

Comment: I can't believe this is actually true :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for  window function

```
sum(QUA) over (partition by INVE_KEY)
```

Note that your sample data for `@TEMP_FINAL` has `QUA = 2` for `INVE_KEY = 1` which isn't what the original sample data was.

```
select 
    *, 
    QUA_MAX = sum(QUA) over (partition by INVE_KEY)
from @TEMP_FINAL
```

And one way to update it would be with a correlated subquery

```
update t1
set QUA_MAX = (select top 1 sum(QUA) over (partition by INVE_KEY) from @TEMP_FINAL t2 where t2.INVE_KEY = t1.INVE_KEY)
from @TEMP_FINAL t1

select * from @TEMP_FINAL
```

Or a CTE

```
;with cte as(
select 
        EVEN_KEY,
        INVE_KEY,
        QUA, 
        QUA_MAX = sum(QUA) over (partition by INVE_KEY)
    from @TEMP_FINAL)

update @TEMP_FINAL 
set QUA_MAX = c.QUA_MAX
from cte c
where c.INVE_KEY = [@TEMP_FINAL].INVE_KEY

select * from @TEMP_FINAL
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try this..

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.QUA_MAX = a.sum_qua
from @temp_final t1,
             (SELECT SUM(QUA) as sum_qua,inve_key
                FROM @TEMP_FINAL t2
                GROUP BY INVE_KEY
               ) a
where t1.INVE_KEY = a.INVE_KEY
```

Comment: @FrenkyB, I think this is the answer you're looking for.

Comment: https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Answer (score 1):

i think that you should add temp_final in the from clause, because you're doing an implicit selfjoin, but you declare just a table as alias t2

Answer (score 0):

So here is your complete code:

```
DECLARE @TEMP_FINAL TABLE
(
    EVEN_KEY INT,
    INVE_KEY INT,
    QUA INT,
    QUA_MAX INT
)

insert into @TEMP_FINAL (even_key, inve_key, qua)
values(1, 2, 1), 
(2,2,2),
(3,2,3),
(1,1,2),
(4,2,3)

UPDATE @TEMP_FINAL
    SET QUA_MAX = (SELECT SUM(QUA)
                FROM @TEMP_FINAL t2 
                WHERE @TEMP_FINAL.INVE_KEY = t2.INVE_KEY 
                GROUP BY INVE_KEY
               )
```

I don't know if I am looking at this wrong but to my it looks like you are doing a where clause comparing that same thing to itself? But instead of doing `@TEMP_FINAL.INVE_KEY = @TEMP_FINAL.INVE_KEY` you're doing `@TEMP_FINAL.INVE_KEY = t2.INVE_KEY`. Sorry for bringing this up I just wanted to verify that this was intentional or not?