# Insert value into table from case expression

Tags: sql

This case expression determines a *current approver* value. I'd like to insert the *current approver* value into the `CURRENT_APPROVER` column (all the same table) every time this case expression is executed. Do you accomplish this by with Insert into? I'm having trouble with the syntax.

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
       WHEN FORM_TYPE IN ('Form_Type1', 'Form_Type2', 'Form_Type3') 
            AND SIGNATURE_FIELD1 IS NULL 
            AND STATUS = 'Pending Approval' 
          THEN 'Signature 1 Needed'
       WHEN FORM_TYPE IN ('Form_Type1', 'Form_Type2', 'Form_Type3') 
            AND SIGNATURE_FIELD2 IS NULL 
            AND STATUS = 'Pending Approval' 
           THEN SIGNATURE_FIELD1_ASSIGNMENT
        WHEN FORM_TYPE IN ('Form_Type1', 'Form_Type2', 'Form_Type3') 
            AND SIGNATURE_FIELD3 IS NULL 
            AND STATUS = 'Pending Approval'  
           THEN SIGNATURE_FIELD2_ASSIGNMENT
        WHEN FORM_TYPE IN ('Form_Type1', 'Form_Type2', 'Form_Type3') 
             AND SIGNATURE_FIELD4 IS NULL 
             AND SIGNATURE_FIELD2 IS NOT NULL 
             AND SIGNATURE_FIELD3 IS NOT NULL 
             AND SIGNATURE_FIELD1 IS NOT NULL 
             AND STATUS = 'Pending Approval'  
            THEN 'Signature 4 Needed'
        ELSE 'Unavailable'
    END AS CURRENT_APPROVER
FROM 
    FINANCE_TABLE;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will set the `CURRENT_APPROVER` to the value from the SELECT CASE where it is null (if all rows has null for this column then the last WHERE condition can be removed). To make the right row get updated with the right value you need to join the inner `SELECT` query to the `UPDATE` query via the primary key of the table. I used `id` as an example but you need to replace this with the real primary key

```
UPDATE FINANCE_TABLE f
SET CURRENT_APPROVER = (SELECT 
                        CASE 
                        WHEN FORM_TYPE IN ('Form_Type1','Form_Type2','Form_Type3') AND SIGNATURE_FIELD1 IS NULL AND STATUS = 'Pending Approval' THEN 'Signature 1 Needed'
                        WHEN FORM_TYPE IN ('Form_Type1','Form_Type2','Form_Type3') AND SIGNATURE_FIELD2 IS NULL AND STATUS = 'Pending Approval' THEN SIGNATURE_FIELD1_ASSIGNMENT
                        WHEN FORM_TYPE IN ('Form_Type1','Form_Type2','Form_Type3') AND SIGNATURE_FIELD3 IS NULL AND STATUS = 'Pending Approval'  THEN SIGNATURE_FIELD2_ASSIGNMENT
                        WHEN FORM_TYPE IN ('Form_Type1','Form_Type2','Form_Type3') AND SIGNATURE_FIELD4 IS NULL AND SIGNATURE_FIELD2 IS NOT NULL AND SIGNATURE_FIELD3 IS NOT NULL AND SIGNATURE_FIELD1 IS NOT NULL AND STATUS = 'Pending Approval'  THEN 'Signature 4 Needed'
                        ELSE 'Unavailable'
                        END AS CURRENT_APPROVER
                        FROM FINANCE_TABLE f2
                        WHERE f.id = f2.id) -- This needs to be updated

WHERE f.CURRENT_APPROVER IS NULL;
```

I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25267083/9223839) as a template for my answer here

Comment: Thanks for getting me on the right track.  I'll continue to play with this but there appears to be a syntax issue.  Incorrect syntax near 'f'. I would want the CURRENT_APPROVER value to be overwritten on each update, so I removed the last Where condition.  The primary key is DOCID so I updated that as well.

Comment: @Jason Maybe you can't use an alias (`f`) here but then you need the full table name inside the subquery, `WHERE FINANCE_TABLE.DOCID = f2.DOCID`. Maybe you could add what database you are using to the question

Comment: The edit you suggested fixed the issue.  Much appreciated!!!! Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP4) (KB4018073) - 11.0.7001.0 (X64)